# Python http request and utf-8 encoding

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, urllib

I use urllib to perform http request to a REST API. All data are in JSON with utf-8 encoding.
The problem is that when i read some special charater via REST API i get the correct encoding (i.e. if i read 90°C the ° is correctly coded as **0xc2 0xb0**) but when i send it back with another request it seems to loose the utf-8 encoding (i.e. ° is coded as **0xb0**).

I made a little test saving the response to file: if i write the response as byte i can see it is coded right, when i load the response as json and then write to file i loose the utf-8 encoding.

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req,context=context)            
r = resp.read()
print(f'resp: {r}')        
f = open('test-utf8','wb')
f.write(r)
f.close()                
content = json.loads(r)
print(content)        
f = open('test2-utf8','w')
f.write(content['descrizione'])
f.close()
```

If i make a new request sending that data after reading it with json.loads, i get this error

```
 unable to decode byte 0xb0 near \'"\'
```

If i use `encode('utf-8')` and `decode('utf-8')` before sending the request it doesn't work.
Where do i mistake?

Comment: Don’t assume the default encoding is UTF-8: `f = open('test2-utf8','w',encoding='utf8')`

Comment: Ok for the file writing that was the problem. Now remains the problem with http request but we suppose is related to our tomcat server. I'll update the post when i'll get further info.

Comment: It's definetly a problem on server side.

Answer (score 0):

After some test we've found out that was an encoding problem on our tomcat RESTful server.